# Python - Errno 2: No such file or directory

Tags: python, cmd, errno

So, im trying to use `subprocess.Popen()` to open a python script in CMD the "complicated" way. Although I cant get it to open due to a space in my PC name. Ive tried using Double Quotes and Single Quotes vut it still doesn't work.

Heres the line of code im trying to execute.

```py
subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe /C python '\Users\Terra Byte\Desktop\jdos3\JDOS3\SYS64\bootthingy.py'")
```

As you can see, I'm using single quotes to wrap the directory path, yet this is the error I get when executing.

```py
C:\Users\Terra Byte\Desktop\jdos3\JDOS3>python: can't open file ''\Users\Terra': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It seems to be completely ignoring my single quotes.

Comment: pass arguments as _list_, and use raw strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never try to build your command name as a *string*.

In this particular case, be aware that single quotes have no protection effect on windows (unlike on Linux/Unix) which explains the quoting you've used is inefficient. Using double quotes would have worked, but it's not the best way.

Never use a string when you can pass the *list* of arguments. This will work:

```
subprocess.Popen(["python",r'\Users\Terra Byte\Desktop\jdos3\JDOS3\SYS64\bootthingy.py'])
```

- use list of strings, unquoted, and let `subprocess` do the work
- remove `cmd /c` prefix, as `python` prefix is enough (alternately, remove `python` to leave `["cmd","/c"` and let file associations do the work)
- use raw string prefix to avoid that backslashes are interpreted